# Calculate Hours in factory by using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There are dates in the cell and times of entering and leaving the factory. I want to calculate how many hours each person has stayed in the day they come to the factory.

I wrote a macro and defined each person as sicil_no since its a unique number. Since there are multiple entries and exits on the same date, I need to calculate for each date and sicil_no (person) first count number of entries and exits then subtract then add them to find total time spent in factory.

Example of my raw data.

| GECIS TARIHI | SICIL NUMARASI | SOYADI | ADI | GEÇİŞ YÖNÜ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04 03 2021 07:06:25 | 02491 | JOHN | CAN | Entry |
| 04 03 2021 09:28:01 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Entry |
| 04 03 2021 15:50:22 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Exit |
| 04 03 2021 17:08:48 | 02491 | JOHN | CAN | Exit |
| 08 03 2021 07:06:45 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Entry |
| 08 03 2021 07:53:37 | 02260 | BABER | YOKY | Entry |
| 08 03 2021 13:05:38 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Exit |
| 08 03 2021 13:18:30 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Entry |
| 08 03 2021 17:23:01 | 02312 | PLAT | JULY | Exit |
| 08 03 2021 19:37:36 | 02260 | BABER | YOKY | Exit |

[image]

```vb
Sub macro()

    Dim sicil_no As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim end_row As Long
    Dim dates As Range
    Dim gecis_yonu As String
    Dim entry As String
    Dim Exits As String
    
    end_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 3 To end_row
        sicil_no = Cells(i, 3).Value
        dates = Cells(i, 1).Value
    
        If Range("J", i).Value = "Exit" Then
            Range("J", i).Value = exist
        End If
        
        If Range("J", i).Value = "Entry" Then
            Range("J", i).Value = entry
        End If
    Next
    
    For Each dates In Range("A", end_row)        
        Range("M", i).Value = exist - entry   
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post links to files. Instead include everything that is needed to understand your question into the question itself. If you want to show something you can add screenshots. See [ask].

Comment: Seems like an excel formula could do it easily. `=24*(FirstOut-FirstIn+IF(SecondOut<>"",SecondOut-SecondIn,0)+IF(ThirdOut<>"",ThirdOut-ThirdIn,0)+IF(FourthOut<>"",FourthOut-FourthIn,0))`  Explanation: If a person takes no breaks, the FirstOut is them leaving at the end of the day. Otherwise, its the start of their first break. The last Out is them going home, whether thats the First or FourthOut.

Comment: @peh i edited. i put a image description

Comment: @Toddleson how should i define second out second and other variables? and should i autofill for the next 6600 row? I write your formula on cell but it gives "name" error

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent (and you have one `Entry` and one `Exit` each day for each person) it should work with the following formula to calculate how many hours in total a person was in the factory (see column D)

```
=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry"))*24
```

and with

```
=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Exit",A:A,">="&INT(A:A),A:A,"<"&INT(A:A)+1)-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry",A:A,">="&INT(A:A),A:A,"<"&INT(A:A)+1))*24
```

you can see how many hours a person was in the factory in each day (see column E).

[image]

---

To show how it works with the example you gave:

- Column F (total hours)
  `=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Entry"))*24`
- Column G (daily hours)
  `=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Exit",A:A,">="&INT(A:A),A:A,"<"&INT(A:A)+1)-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Entry",A:A,">="&INT(A:A),A:A,"<"&INT(A:A)+1))*24`
- Column H (corrected total hours)
  `=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Entry")+IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,E:E,"Entry")>COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,E:E,"Exit"),MAXIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,E:E,"Entry"),0))*24`

Note that if there is a `Entry` that has no corresponding `Exit` this might occur in the end. Then you need to remove that last `Entry` from the calculation, to calculate properly. This is what I tried with the corrected formula.

See that last `Entry` in red has no `Exit`. The formula in H will remove that `Entry` from calculation.

[image]

Comment: no, as you can see in the picture there are multiple entry exists in a day for just 1 person. And there is a inconsistency about data that there might be some exceptions as two entry consecutively then exit. For example entry-entry-exit-entry-exit. this formula above resulted 0 when i try it

Comment: This formula can handle multiple entries and exits each day as you can see in my example (the red values) where person `02491` comes twice on day `2021-03-04` and it calculates correctly. • Make sure your dates are real numeric dates and not text looking like a date. You need numeric dates to be able to calculate with it. This formula works as long as each `Entry` has an `Exit` as shown in my example.

Comment: *"there might be some exceptions as two entry consecutively then exit"* Note that one person cannot enter 2 times consecutively without exiting in between. This is physically not possible. If you have such wrong data you need to eliminate it first no matter if you want to use a formula or a VBA script. False data needs to be eliminated.

Comment: I use your formula and change my date format as your like "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM" stil look 0 what should i do? how is yours

Comment: You need to start with a small sample of your data. Don't use your entire data, use a sample only, to get it work. Later you can use more data. Make sure in your sample every `Entry` has an `Exit`. The date format doesn't matter as long as they are numeric dates. Test if you hava a numeric date with this forumla `=VALUE(A2)` where `A2` is the cell you want to test. If the result of this formula is a number similar to `44256,2961` then it is a numeric date (that is perfect) if it shows `#VALUE!` as error your dates are not dates but text (that means you cannot calculate with them).

Comment: I followed your advice i am trying with a small sample and i checkd value formula it worked so date format is numeric thats also okay, but i couldnt figure out why I get 0 as result. Since column names and places are the same as your when i copy paste your formula it should have been worked

Comment: Well I have no idea what you did wrong. But you can see in my answer that it actually worked.

Comment: yes it works in your example. Even if I just copy paste your formulas, how can i make mistake. Only difference is i put ; instead , because it works like this in my region. =(SUMIFS(A:A;C:C;C:C;J:J;"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A;C:C;C:C;J:J;"Entry"))*24

Comment: Can you put some example data into your question that you tried? So maybe I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: thats how i do  =(SUMIFS(A:A;C:C;C:C;J:J;"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A;C:C;C:C;J:J;"Entry"))*24   the image in the question is a part of real data

Comment: Can you please add the data formatted as text or [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) into your question? I'm not going to type that data on my keyboard.

Comment: I didnt undertsand how to put table format i copy paste but i guess i didnt worked. I can share onedrive link of sample?

Comment: @peh do you mind if i send onedrive link or smt if you have diffilculty to copy paste? Because i really need you to help me to solve this problem :( https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgI-tSFCWpMKgQk3EjoOL5Mwr0Cv?e=NyzESB

Comment: I got a new error as ##### written in the formula and in the comment part of formula says date and time are negative or too long

Comment: The formula is worked now but it gives a negative value as -1062223,107

Comment: See my edit. It also works with your example. • Note that you get negative numbers if there is an `Entry` but an `Exit` is missing. Use `=COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry")` and `=COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,J:J,"Exit")` to count entries and exits and you will see that where a negative number is there is more entries than exits. So you need to make sure that there is an Exit for every Entry in your data or you cannot calculate properly. In your example file if I put these both formulas I get 11 entries but only 10 exits. So you probably need to eliminate the last entry of that person to be able to calculate

Comment: To remove the last `Entry` in that case where no `Exit` exists you can try to use `=(SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Exit")-SUMIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry")+IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry")>COUNTIFS(C:C,C:C,J:J,"Exit"),MAXIFS(A:A,C:C,C:C,J:J,"Entry"),0))*24` in your example file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, In the beginning of my question I wrote that i need a macro solution. Could you pls help me about macro codes? Maybe you can record because i couldnt get true result, i can try that one to?

Comment: Macros are slower and much more complicated than formulas. The problems you face in VBA would exactly be the same as with formulas, as the calculation would be the same. Further your code is too far from working to give an answer (we can help to fix a specific issue in the code but we cannot write code for you). I highly recommend to use a formula solution.

Comment: okay see my edit on question. Can you help me to fixed macro that I create

Comment: You can't imagine how much i want to solv this problem but your formulas get 0 as result on my excel :(

Comment: Then you probably just didn't adjust the addresses in the formulas to your columns correctly. The formula columns like `A:A`, `C:C` and `E:E` match the columns in the pictures I show. Make sure if you use them you replace them to match **your** columns. Otherwise it will not calculate correctly.

Comment: yes i already did it, i changed but it gives still 0. on macro solution could you help me fix the problem? for this row: dates = Cells(i, 1).Value it gives an error and says object vairable or with block are not set

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the code that is too far from anything that would work (sorry I have to say that). The formulas definitely work as you can see in my example. And again if the formulas calculate wrong your code would be wrong too as it has to use the same calculation.

Comment: okay but in thay question i told that vba solution is required too many times... thanks in advance